# My worker Celery works in localhost but not in heroku

Tags: django, heroku, celery

I set up the workers on my localhost (windows) and it works perfectly but on heroku it doesn't work.

I'm using Django, Reddis and Celery.

celery.py

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'eco_gestao.settings')

app = Celery('eco_gestao')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn eco_gestao.wsgi --log-file -
worker: celery -A eco_gestao worker -l info
```

settings:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://'
# BROKER_URL = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://127.0.0.1:6380')
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'

redis_host = os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost')
# Channel layer definitions
# http://channels.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploying.html#setting-up-a-channel-backend
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        # This example app uses the Redis channel layer implementation asgi_redis
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [(redis_host, 6379)],
        },
        "ROUTING": "multichat.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}
```

Erro:

```
[2019-08-21 17:33:22,075: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://localhost:6379//: Error 111 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection refused.
```

Comment: Do you have Redis running on localhost on Heroku? If not, there is your problem...

Comment: @DejanLekic, I've Heroku Redis and Redis Cloud in my heroku :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure Celery running on Heroku to use your Heroku redis by exporting the correct REDIS_HOST value (I see that you are picking the Redis host from the environment). Obviously that value is not exported (that is why you are getting `Cannot connect to redis://localhost:6379//`).

Comment: woooh, Thanks so much for all suport.